# Can I pass a Set (Data Structure) from AJAX to Servlet?

Tags: ajax, servlets

Can't we pass any data structure (apart from Array) from AJAX to the servlet?

I have created a Set and added some elements to it. When I pass it to Servlet using AJAX, servlet receives `null`. I tried using `JSON.stringify()` but then servlet is receiving an empty set `{}`. I tried the same with `Array` and it's working fine with `JSON.stringify()`

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var set = new Set();
set.add("1");
set.add("2"); 
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url : 'Servlet_Name',
    data : {
        set: JSON.stringify(set)            
    },
    success : function(responseText) {
        // Do Something...
    }
});
```

SERVLET CODE

```
doPost(all parameters){
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("set"));
}
```

Expected result:
{"1","2"}

Actual result:
{}

Comment: Are you missing contentType: 'application/json' ?

Comment: Also, if you are expecting json back, dataType: 'json' might help here.

Comment: @NiteRain I don't think adding contentType would help as the same code was working fine with Array.

Comment: Let me know what worked.  Seems like a parsing issue on the server side not knowing what type of data is being sent to it and it figured incorrectly.

Comment: I'd try to list all the parameters from the `request` for both cases (posting an Array, and a Set), to see what is the difference.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I can't understand how would that be helpful when an empty Set is being received by the servlet.

Comment: @TBag it could help you to understand what happens when you change the data type from Array to Set. Important information is also what browser do you use / because e.g. Internet Explorer does not fully support Set.

Comment: Did you attempt to see what happens after the JSON.stringify?  I just went to my console in my chrome browser.  and wrote var set = new Set(); set.add(1); set.add(4); and then JSON.stringify(set); and the string it comes out with is {}.

Comment: If you want something that JSON.stringify can use, probably, store an associate array like: set = []; set["alpha"]=1; set["1"]=1; set["2"]=1; and when you get to part to send via ajax, just use JSON.stringify(Object.keys(set));